# Don't run npm scripts postinstall on devDependencies

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I am creating some private npm packages and have a `postinstall` script on those packages. The `postinstall` script works great when I'm developing on the package, but the problem I'm running into is when I bring in the package into another project and do an install, it's running the devDependency `postinstall` script.

I don't want it to do that, I only want it to do the `postinstall` if I'm doing the install from that directory. How can I do this or what I can I use instead of `postinstall` to accomplish the same without running into this problem?